# SQL Upsert statement not working on non indexed column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL v9.6.6. I am running the following SQL:

```
insert into t_vs_config_key (name, description, is_brand_dependent)
  values ('ucp.cluster','UCP Cluster', true)
  ON CONFLICT (name) DO UPDATE SET is_brand_dependent=true;
```

This results in the following error, because the `name` column is not indexed as unique. I cannot add an index, because there is existing data that is not unique.

> ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON
>   CONFLICT specification

**Question**
Any ideas how to do the upsert statement without the index?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to do it without unique index

Comment: And if you use `ON CONFLICT (name, description, is_brand_dependent)` ?

Comment: @ AnonyDev It gets the same error if I try `ON CONFLICT (name, description, is_brand_dependent)`

Comment: Maybe a reply here but not sure : https://medium.com/@betakuang/why-postgresqls-on-conflict-cannot-find-my-partial-unique-index-552327b85e1

Comment: Becasue there is not conflict if you don't have unique index/primary key. Conflict of DB is then when it is impossible to make something (for example put non unique value into unique index).

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can not use `ON CONFLICT` without a unique index.

However you can ensure that future inserts are unique by adding a new column to your table that indicates if the rows are valid or not and creating a partial unique index based on that flag:

```
alter t_vs_config_key 
  add column valid boolean not null default false;
```

This will initialize all existing rows to `valid = false`

Now for future rows, change the default for this column to `true`

```
alter table t_vs_config_key
    alter column valid set default true;
```

and make sure no "invalid" rows can be inserted any more by adding a check constraint:

```
alter table t_vs_config_key  
  add constraint check_valid check (valid);
```

Now you can create a unique index:

```
create unique index on t_vs_config_key(name)
where valid;
```

which can be used for an `on conflict` clause:

```
insert into t_vs_config_key (name, description, is_brand_dependent)
values ('ucp.cluster','UCP Cluster', true)
ON CONFLICT (name) where valid DO UPDATE 
  SET is_brand_dependent = true;
```

Note the `where valid` clause in the statement.